# Is it right to have lots of onTouchListener?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing a piano app , it's not the best , but it's a start .

I'm using below code to play sound and change image of button with touch event.

```
        C4.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // PRESSED
                    if (Sustain == "false" ) {

                        streamI25 = sp.play(SC4, Volume, Volume, 0, 0, 1);
                        C4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.whitekey1cilicked);
                    }

                    else {

                        sp.play(SC4, Volume, Volume, 0, 0, 1);
                        C4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.whitekey1cilicked);
                    }

                    // just in case somthings happend
                    final Handler handler2 = new Handler();
                    handler2.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //Do something after 100ms
                            C4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.whitekey1);
                        }
                    }, keyUpTime);


                    return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // RELEASED


                    C4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.whitekey1);

                    final Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //Do something after 100ms
                            sp.pause(streamI25);

                        }
                    }, releaseTime);


                    return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Is it right ? Is it not dumb to write all of this code for every single key in piano ?

I can use just few line of code for all of my button in OnClick method , but I need events of onTouch . Is it correct to write 72 onTouchListener  ?

Comment: I am not one to say very much experience wise.  However if you wanted to do it this way, I personally would create a class for the piano key and create your keys as objects and store them in an array. that way you could give them each everything they need, AND save a lot of space.  That's only if you choose to do it this exact way though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would better implement the OnTouchListener in your activity or another handling class that you extend with `implements OnTouchListener`. Your view can have a tag that you analyse then in your methods (the view is passed as parameter to the function call).

You could write

```
class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener
```

and then

```
C4.setTag("C4"); // or by XML
C4.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

and in onTouch you change the `view` instead of `C4` and select the sound based on the tag.

Answer (score 1):

Repeating the exact same code  many times is always a bad idea. One option here is to create a named class such add PianoKeyTouchListener which contains this event handling code.